# How to access SetThreadDescription() in Windows 2016 Server, Version 1607

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, dll, windows-server-2016

If I just call `SetThreadDescription()` from WinAPI, it works on Windows 10, Version 2004. However, on Windows 2016 Server, 1607 it produces the following message box:

> The procedure entry point SetThreadDescription could not be located in the dynamic link library

and the path to my executable program follows in the message.

According to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setthreaddescription):

> SetThreadDescription is only available by Run Time Dynamic Linking on
>   Windows Server 2016, 1607.

So I tried dynamic linking as follows:

```
typedef HRESULT (WINAPI *TSetThreadDescription)(HANDLE, PCWSTR);

namespace {
  TSetThreadDescription gpSetThreadDescription = nullptr;
}

void Initialize() {
  HMODULE hKernel32 = GetModuleHandleA("Kernel32.dll");
  if (hKernel32 == nullptr) {
    cerr << "FATAL: failed to get kernel32.dll module handle, error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
    quick_exit(5);
  }
  gpSetThreadDescription = reinterpret_cast<TSetThreadDescription>(
    GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "SetThreadDescription"));
  if (gpSetThreadDescription == nullptr) {
    cerr << "FATAL: failed to get SetThreadDescription() address, error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
    quick_exit(6);
  }
}
```

This code also works on Windows 10. However, I'm getting error 127 ("The specified procedure could not be found") on Windows Server 2016.

What am I doing wrong about the run-time dynamic linking?

Comment: You are calling `GetLastError` at a point where it will not return a meaningful value anymore. Whatever you write to `std::cerr` is of no use, until you fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, despite MSDN says "DLL: Kernel32.dll", the function is actually in `KernelBase.DLL`, so I've fixed the problem after changing to:

```
HMODULE hKernelBase = GetModuleHandleA("KernelBase.dll");
```

Comment: possible also use `NtSetInformationThread / NtQueryInformationThread` with undocumented and undeclared [*`ThreadNameInformation`*](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/ntoskrnl/api/ps/psquery/class.htm) advantage here - you can set not only string but any binary data up to 64kb size and you can use static linking with *ntdll.dll* - *NtSetInformationThread / NtQueryInformationThread* exist everywhere, simply before win10 it return `STATUS_NOT_IMPLEMENTED`

Comment: @rbm You cannot statically link a DLL. You can use [Load-Time Dynamic Linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/load-time-dynamic-linking) or [Run-Time Dynamic Linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/run-time-dynamic-linking).

Comment: @IInspectable - ok, i mean *Load-Time Dynamic Linking*. and we both known at begin what i mean

Comment: Hi,@Serge,  you could also [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).